# Why does Optional.of().ifPresent() create an Optional inside ifPresent()?

Tags: java

I have code similar to the following:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

Optional<String> test = Optional.of("test");

Optional.of(test).ifPresent(optStr -> optStr.ifPresent(str -> result.add(str)));
```

What I don't understand is why I have to do two `ifPresent()` calls instead of just doing this...

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

Optional<String> test = Optional.of("test");

Optional.of(test).ifPresent(str -> result.add(str));
```

If I have already called `ifPresent()` once on an `Optional`, shouldn't that allow me to get the value from the `Optional` after the `ifPresent()`?

Comment: Why do you ignore the fact you call `Optional.of` with an Optional as argument? What else than `Optional<Optional<String>>` do you expect to get there?

Comment: you can use `Optional.of(test).ifPresent(str -> result.add(str.orElse("default")));`

Comment: Because you are creating an `Optional` of `Optional` of `String`?

Comment: oops...my bad...guess I should update my `Optional.of()` block to be a `String` rather than an `Optional`

Comment: or I could just do `test.ifPresent(str -> result.add(str))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created an `Optional<Optional<String>>`, the first `ifPresent` strips the outer `Optional`, and leaves you with an `Optional<String>`. You have to call `ifPresent` on that inner `Optional` in order to get to the `String`.